# Specify component caption position?

Tags: java, components, position, vaadin, caption

I've been wondering. Using Vaadin, is there a way to specify where the caption of a component should appear in regards to the component main object (eg. Select, TextField, etc..).

I'm trying to get the caption of a Select to be displayed in front of the Select object. By default the caption is displayed on top of the object.

It would be neat if I could specify where the caption should be displayed and without having to add a Label and the Select component into a HorizontalLayout to get it the way I want.

Anyone have any suggestions? =)

Comment: damn, this question was extremely uninteresting it seems... =\

Comment: Use FormLayout: http://vaadin.com/book/-/page/layout.components.formlayout.html

Comment: Any option other than FormLayout because this layout is very limited. For example you can't have two columns of fields such as have firstname and lastname on the same row in the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IkarusAbsoluteLayout in [IkarusWidget](http://vaadin.com/addon/ikaruswidget) addon does exactly this behaviour.